# Automating the hidden field in Web form filling through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba to automate a  web form filing site in Internet Explorer. I have been very successful to this point. The issue I am running into is that there is an input field and the type is "hidden" and not text. After running the 1st code the 2nd field will auto populate which was hidden till now. It populates only when we enter value in the previous field. It is a dropdown field so we need to select the value from the dropdown list. So when I am trying to automate it, the hidden field is not auto populating by itself as it is the case in the manual process. How do I get around this? I know there is got to be a way.

This is the code which I am using.

```
Sub automaticformfilling_ARGOS()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
 'to make sure that the website is properly loaded
With ie
.Visible = True
.navigate "https://www.argos-pet-insurance.com/quoteAndBuy.do?e=e1s1&curPage=captureDetails&rakT=1510852044896.1391473424.994101.1731.881880349.846|tsid:9904"

Do While .Busy
DoEvents
Loop
Do While .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
End With
 Set BreedType = ie.document.getElementById("yourDetailsPolicyHolderBreedTypes0")
   BreedType.selectedIndex = 2

Set BreedName = ie.document.getElementById("breedTypeAhead")
   BreedName.selectedIndex = 1
    End Sub
```

The HTML code for the 1st field is

```
<select name="pets[0].breedType" class="select-large changeTriggered"
 id="yourDetailsPolicyHolderBreedTypes0" onchange="FormTaggingMain('',
 1500);" data-di-field-id="pets0BreedType"><option
 id="petBreedTypesSelectVoidOption" selected="selected" value="">Please
select</option><option id="petBreedTypesSelectOptions1"
value="NWA_PET_C">Cross Breed</option><option
id="petBreedTypesSelectOptions2" value="NWA_PET_P">Pedigree</option><option
id="petBreedTypesSelectOptions3" value="NWA_PET_S">Small mixed breed (up to 
10kg)</option><option id="petBreedTypesSelectOptions4"
value="NWA_PET_B">Medium mixed breed (10 - 20kg)</option><option
id="petBreedTypesSelectOptions5" value="NWA_PET_L">Large mixed breed (above
20kg)</option></select>
```

Whereas the HTML code for the hidden field is

```
<input class="typeahead large-input hasPlaceholder tt-input"
id="breedTypeAhead" style='vertical-align: top; position: relative;
background-image: ur("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
"); background-color: transparent;' dir="auto" spellcheck="false"
 onblur="breedChange(this);" onchange="breedChange(this);
 placeholder="Please start typing" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Can you give the web address? What value did you want to assign (presumably whatever is at index 1) and what was the expected output?

Comment: Hi QHarr, Thanks for replying.  The web address is "https://www.argos-pet-insurance.com/quoteAndBuy.do?e=e1s1&curPage=captureDetails&rakT=1515415253159.690539665.045787.1731.392350935.6110|tsid:9904&_ga=2.150095542.1683361357.1515415252-1168919733.1515415252" . There is 1 field which is hidden at first. It populates only when we enter value in the previous field. It is a dropdown field so we need to select the value from the dropdown list. So when I am trying to automate it, the hidden field is not auto populating by itself as it is the case in the manual process.

Comment: What I am aiming is through automation the field pops up on its own and select the desired value from the dropdown